# How to make this react component have items aligned to the left and container in the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to implement this design basically, [image: Prototype of the design]

When i make this component my design looks like this:
[image: Implemented prototype]

However, i am not being able to put the container in the center and items on left alignment.

Here is my code

```
<div className="container1">
            <h1 className = "header">Payment<br/> Information</h1>
            <p className = "label" >Card Number</p>
            <input className = "CardValues" type="text" name="name" placeholder = "0000-0000-0000-0000"/>
            <p className = "label">Name on card</p>
            <input className = "CardValues" type="text" name="name" placeholder = "e.g. john smith"/>
            <div>
              <p className = "label">Date on card</p>
              <input className = "CardValues" type="text" name="name" placeholder = "mm/yy"/>
              <p className = "label">Security Code</p>
              <input className = "CardValues" type="text" name="name"  placeholder = "***"/>
            </div>
            <div className = "SaveButton">
            <input type = "Submit" className = "saveButton" value="Save Changes"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.container1{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: left;
}

.header{
    font-family: "futura-pt";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 31px;
    line-height: 120%;
    color: #18214D;
    width: 212px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.label{
    color: #18214D;
    font-family: "futura-pt";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

.saveButton{
    background: #74D173;
    border-radius: 28px;
    font-family: "futura-pt";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    bottom: 32px;
}

.CardValues{
    background: #EFF2F6;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

input[value^="Save Changes"] {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-family: "futura-pt";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

i tried `justify-content`, `align-items`. But none of them seem to be working. For some reason my container has the margin and width set by default which if i try to overrride by writing `margin: 0px`. it still doesn't get deleted.

Comment: add ```margin: auto``` for container1.

Comment: added it. i also added a `<center>` tag around the parent `div`. Now my container is in center but the items inside are also in center. How can i make those align to the left? I have `justify-content: left;align-items: left;` in my container.

Comment: ?? do not use the HTML tag center, obsolete for ages  (html4) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: ok. i see. the text align is not working as expected either though.